# Faking a repository - faking Find method

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, repository-pattern

For my unit testing, I need to fake a Repository.  I have easily been able to fake all the methods except for the Find method which takes in a Linq Expression delegate as a parameter.

My fake repository code is listed below (unnecessary code removed).  The code I have tried using is shown in the Find method. The compiler error I get from VS is:

*"System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has some invalid arguments"*

Any ideas on how I *bend* the criteria parameter into the argument type required?

```
public class FakeCourseRepository : IRepository<Course>
{
    private List<Course> courseList;

    public FakeCourseRepository(List<Course> courses)
    {
        courseList = courses;
    }

    public IList<Course> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Course, bool>> criteria)
    {
        return courseList.Where<Course>(criteria);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
 return courseList.Where<Course>(criteria);
```

to

```
 return courseList.AsQueryable().Where<Course>(criteria).ToList();
```

You're trying to pass an Expression, normally used with IQueryables, into an overload of Where designed to work with IEnumerables and which takes a straight delegate. You're also returning an IQueryable when your method clearly says it gives back an IList. Whether you really need an IList, or if you can get away with a concrete List (which is also IEnumerable and IQueryable and thus allows for easier further manipulation) is a topic for another discussion, but understand that ILists, as ILists, cannot be iterated; you'll have to use or implement an AsEnumerable() method to convert it into an iterable format.

Comment: Thanks KeithS, this was a very helpful answer. I will also look into your suggestion around a concrete List.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a mocking framework for unit testing repositories.

Comment: Usually that's a good idea, but simple defined mocks like this have value as well, especially for mocking data storage. Mock expectations can be tricky to manage (you have to expect EXACTLY what you want, no more or less), whereas evaluating the validity of an object given to an in-memory mock like this is much more straightforward.